# EF Core: loading related entities - circular dependency

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have 2 related entities in EF Core (database first design from an existing database) and having trouble loading one-many relationship - it's a webapi ASP.NET core 1.0 application

Brand Entity

```
 [Table("tblBranding")]
public class Brand {
    [Key]
    [Column("brandingId")]
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    [Column("BrandingActive")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Column("DeadBrand")]        
    public bool DeadBrand { get; set; }
    [Column("BrandingSiteTitle")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Event entity:

```
[Table("tblEvents")]
public class Event
{   
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    [Column("eventActive")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [Column("eventName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public DateTime EventCloseDate {get;set;}        
    public int PaxAllocationLimit { get; set; }

    //navigation properties                
    [Column("BrandingId")]
    public int BrandId { get; set; }        
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

}
```

code from for FLUID API in OnModelCreating in DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Brand)
            .WithMany(b => b.Events).HasForeignKey(e=>e.BrandId);

    public virtual DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
```

code from BrandsController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        //var brands = from b in _context.Brands
        //             where b.Active == true
        //             orderby b.BrandName
        //             select b;

        var brands = _context.Brands.Include(e => e.Events).Where(b => b.Active == true).OrderBy(b => b.Name);

        return new ObjectResult(brands);
    }
```

code from EventsController

```
 // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet("{id:int?}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int? id) {
        var events = from e in _context.Events
                     where e.Active == true
                     orderby e.Name
                     select e;

        if (!events.Any()) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if (id != null) {
            events = events.Where(e => e.EventId == id).OrderBy(e => 0);
            if (events.Count() == 0) { return HttpNotFound(); }
            return new ObjectResult(events);
        }
        else {
            return new ObjectResult(events);
        }
    }
```

When I try to load brands through the API, I get an exception:

Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory: Information: Executed DbCommand (80ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [t].[EventId], [t].[EventCloseDate], [t].[eventActive], [t].[BrandingId], [t].[EventId1], [t].[eventName], [t].[PaxAllocationLimit]
FROM [tblEvents] AS [t]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [e].[BrandingSiteTitle], [e].[brandingId]
    FROM [tblBranding] AS [e]
    WHERE [e].[BrandingActive] = 1
) AS [e] ON [t].[BrandingId] = [e].[brandingId]
ORDER BY [e].[BrandingSiteTitle], [e].[brandingId]
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory: Error: An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'EventId1'.

Apart from this, is there a way to load related entities without using the "Includes" ? If I do not use include and use the standard LINQ query, the related entities are loaded as NULL

**UPDATE**

I'm now getting an invalid column error - i noticed in my previous code I hadn't used virtual on the ICollection in brand

now i can't figure out why is it generating EventId1 column in the SQL

EF 7 version is 1.0.0-rc1-final

**UPDATE-2**
After playing around with the code the Exception changed to circular dependency exception in code given the exact same code as above - I don't know why it was generating the invalid column name earlier (EventId1)

Comment: Where does the exception occur ? When serializing the response ? Can you check that query.FirstOrDefault() do not throw any exception ?

Comment: updated the code and problem I'm having -  i think i was having the previous issue because i hadn't used virtual on the collections property

Comment: Are you using EF Migration ?

Comment: using EF Scaffolding - from an existing database -however , the tables in the database are huge, my models are simplified versions of the table for what I need for the API with mapping in the modelBuilder

Comment: I've built a sample solution based on the information you provide and don't have any errors

Comment: hmm.. odd.. let me try a few other things - otherwise i'll do some cleanup and package up the solution to upload somewhere along side the actual dbscripts and sample data

Comment: I've used FirstorDefault(), getting no error, on normal full select
- now for some reason error has switched back to : Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel: Error: An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Brand' with type 'SGSAPI.Models.Brand'. Path '[0].Events[0]'.

although there are mo apparent code differences that I can see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question here - figured it out-

the 2 entities used here, I've used fully defined relationships in the EF 7
- however the JSON serializer doesn not like that,as this createsa circular dependancy - Brand Contains Events List, and each event also contains the parent  brand property -

so the solution here was to add [JsonIgnore] attribute to relationship properties on the child

updated Events class:

```
[Table("tblEvents")]
public class Event
{   
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    [Column("eventActive")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [Column("eventName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public DateTime EventCloseDate {get;set;}        
    public int PaxAllocationLimit { get; set; }

    //navigation properties             
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Column("brandingId")]
    public virtual int BrandId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: well you dont have to `[JsonIgnore]` the ID but you have to ignore the child objects and/or the child list objects